# How to trigger change in sha256sum of rendered configmap in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a setting in my `configmap.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: V2.23
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: my-configmap
data: 
   image.tag: {{ .Values.image.tag }}
```

Then in `deployment.yaml` I have this line:

```
  annotations:
    checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

Then in `values.yaml` I have this line:

```
image:
  repository: myrepo
  tag: latest
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

If I have the following `helm` command in my `Jenkinsfile`

```
        sh """
          helm upgrade --install --force \
          --namespace=default \
          --values=values.yaml \
          --set image.tag=${output_of_git-describe} \
          --set image.pullPolicy=Always \
          myimage kubernetes/myimage
       """
```

**Question**

1. Will the `sha256` for `configmap.yaml` actually get changed based on the helm command I have in my `Jenkinsfile`?
2. Is there a `helm` command I can run to display the sha256 of `configmap.yaml`?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Will the sha256 for configmap.yaml actually get changed based on the helm command I have in my Jenkinsfile?

Yes.  The `include` function will render the `configmap.yaml` template using the current helm values.

> 2. Is there a helm command I can run to display the sha256 of configmap.yaml?

Yes.  This is what the `helm template` command does.  For example:

```
$ helm template --set image.tag=foo mychart | grep checksum
        checksum/config: bd280ed35fb0f343eb93837290a67e26423f0aa247f48b522f574a711fa35e11
```

```
$ helm template --set image.tag=bar mychart | grep checksum
        checksum/config: 152533d214421480233406153edcde673f4ce072fba940cb7cfbab96954f7201
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've written it ([from here](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)), Helm will calculate the SHA-256 hash of the unrendered template file, which won't change as you update the value.

If your ConfigMap will only ever contain this single value, you could use a hash of that value instead:

```
checksum/config: {{ sha256sum .Values.image.tag }}
```

You could break out the contents of the ConfigMap into a separate renderable template:

```
{{/* _config_map.tpl */}}
{{- define "config-map-contents" -}}
image.tag: {{ .Values.image.tag }}
{{- end -}}
```

```
{{/* my-configmap.yaml */}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: my-configmap
data: {{ include "config-map-contents" | nindent 2 }}
```

```
{{/* in the pod spec */}}
checksum/config: {{ include "config-map-contents" | sha256sum }}
```

At the end of the day, you need *something* in the pod spec to change to cause Kubernetes to redeploy it.  In Helm you can more directly put the value in an environment variable without going via a ConfigMap, which will have the right effect:

```
env:
  - name: IMAGE_TAG
    value: {{ .Values.image.tag }}
```

Or if it actually is the image tag, simply changing the target image of a container in a pod will cause it to redeploy:

```
image: {{ printf "%s/%s:%s" .Values.image.repository (.Values.image.image | default "myimage") .Values.image.tag | quote}}
```

Comment: "Helm will calculate the SHA-256 hash of the unrendered template file, which won't change as you update the value."

I don't think this is correct.  The `include` function does render the template using the helm values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example first I have created the content to `values.yaml`

```
#values.yaml
configMap:
  content: |
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Hello World"'
```

Here you can see I am referring to the example script from values.yaml

```
#config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: my-configmap
data: 
  key: {{ .Values.secret.content | b64enc }}
```

Then the actual deployment

```
***
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/apache-config: {{ printf .Values.configMap.content | sha256sum  }}
***
```

Now you can see in action

```
$ helm upgrade --install example-helm ./example-helm
Release "example-helm" does not exist. Installing it now.
NAME: example-helm
LAST DEPLOYED: Sun Mar 20 22:46:09 2022
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=example-helm,app.kubernetes.io/instance=example-helm" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
```

After I did deploy then I did small changes to the script content

```
configMap:
  content: |
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Hello World to Stack Overflow"'
```

Now you can see its getting updated

```
$ kubectl get pod                                             
NAME                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
example-helm-5bf5457b4-wgsx7    1/1     Running             0          26s
example-helm-668b4d7d78-9bh2g   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
```

Comment: Note that if you need to refer variables or named imports on the configmap this won't work for you.